# Swift IOS transparent view over original view. Overlay. Subview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, swift2, drawrect

I can use the following code to override drawRect() in swift, which works fine.

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
  var path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
  UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
  path.fill()
}
```

I want to add subview(or second view) over the original view.

```
var overlayView = UIView()
self.view.addSubview(overlayView)
```

My question is, how can I override the drawRect() of a subview?

Or, how can I just make the subview a new view instead and place it over the original view?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `UIView` subclass, e.g.

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```

Then replace `var overlayView = UIView()` with `var overlayView = MyCustomView()`

Comment: I also tried putting 
override func vewDidLoad() {}
in this new class, but I get method does not override any method from it's superclass. Any ideas?